# Linking Database of Android App to World

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm fairly new to the world of Computer Science, and I have questions that I am not sure where/how to look for an answer for them, otherwise I would have just googled. 
So, I made an app in android, and it has a SQLite database. Right now, I am the only one who uses this app, it's not even published...the app is like any other social network website where you post something, and others comment on it. So right now, I'm the only one who posts and comments, and the results are all saved in SQLite database in my phone.
How can I "publish" my database to the world? So other people could access the database too? add comments to it etc. when they have the app installed on their device.

What topics of computer science I need to learn to go with this?
I'm sure there's a simple answer to this, but I don't know where/what to look for.
If there are any links to websites, or similar questions on here that could help please post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have developed an app with db that is in client side

In order to be accessed from everywhere ... you have to use centralized Data base server like sql-server,oracle or my sql...

you have to link you local db to server db for that you need a API(Application programming interface) it can be developed using various languages such as php,c#,java etc..

I hope this would be helpful enough for you.

Comment: Hmm still confused.... what good is SQLite for? so I will need to re-implement my modules to use mySQL instead of SQLite?

Comment: @Ashl7 - SQLite is meant for stand alone application like mobile apps.What you have done so far is right.mySQL is centralised DB it will collect from and give data to your mobile app of all the devices.In-Order to connect both mobile apps and centralised DB you need API which is written using php,c#,java etc. ...what you exactly need is lets say ...learn php and learn how to host it on apache web server then learn how to use mysql with php to store and retireve data from it. you have already done moible app part with local db so don't confuse with server side part.

Comment: Thank you sir, just another question: 
Would it be be possible to use Python, Java and C++ or a combination of these instead of PHP and Apache? I really don't wanna learn another programming language lol

Comment: @Ashl7 - you can use Java with the combination of apache or tomcat server because it is easy, then you just have to call the php web api's in android app so that it will store the data in my sql centraised db and get data from it.It's always better to get help from java or php or some other developers..bcuz your specilization is mobile apps and its ok not to learn other languages too